# Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional. If $T: V\rightarrow V$ is diagonalizable with $n$ distinct eigenvalues, then $V$ is cyclic as a $K[x]$ module.

Tags: linear-algebra

***Problem:*** Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over a field $K$. Suppose that $T:V \rightarrow V$ is diagonalizable with $n$ distinct eigenvalues. Then I wish to show that $V$ is cyclic as a $K[x]$ module.

I know that by Cayley-Hamilton that $p(char(x))(v)=0$ for all $v \in V$ and that for any $v_i$ that $Ann(v_i) \subset Ann(V)$ but I am not sure how to get the desired conclusion. Hints appreciated.

Edit: In particular it seems that I would have to show that $Ann(v_i)$ could not have all have degree less than $n$  as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $v_i$ be an eigenvector for $\lambda_i$ then $\sum v_i$ will generate $V$ as a $K[x]$ module. This is because the action of $x^k$ sends this vector to 
$$\sum \lambda^k_iv_i$$ and these vectors are linearly independent (for $0\leq k\leq n-1$) from the Vandermond matrix, here we use the fact that the eigenvalues are distinct.

Answer (score 1):

One way to prove this is by using the [invariant factor decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain#Invariant_factor_decomposition). The minimal polynomial is the largest invariant factor, while the characteristic polynomial is the product of the invariant factors; since both polynomials are equal here (both are $(X-\lambda_1)\ldots(X-\lambda_n)$) there is just one invariant factor and the module is cyclic.

---

If you want to avoid this somewhat heavy theorem, another way is to classify the submodules of this $K[X]$ module (in other words the $T$-invariant subspaces). The minimal polynomial of a submodule must be a divisor of the global minimal polynomial $(X-\lambda_1)\ldots(X-\lambda_n)$, from which it follows that any submodule is the sum of a certain subset of the eigenspaces (they are precisely classified by the $2^n$ monic divisors of $(X-\lambda_1)\ldots(X-\lambda_n)$). Then any vector with a nonzero projection on each of the eigenspaces is outside any proper submodule; it follows that it is a cyclic vector.